# Knockout/JQuery currency format

Tags: jquery, knockout.js, currency-formatting

I have the below page working pretty well (I've cut out some other fields and styling to keep the sample that I post here smallish). I'd like the Premium line in the table (line 17) to format as currency (USD). What's the best way of doing this?

```
<asp:Content ID="Content2" ContentPlaceHolderID="ContentPlaceHolder1" runat="server">
    <div class="datagrid" >
        <table >
            <thead>
                <tr>
                    <th>Location Name</th>
                    <th>Location Total</th>
                </tr>
            </thead>
            <tbody data-bind="foreach: { data: Locations, as: 'location' }">
                <tr>
                    <td><span data-bind="text: location.LocationName" /> </td>
                    <td><span data-bind="text: location.Premium" /> </td>
                </tr>
            </tbody>
        </table>
    </div>

    <script>
        $(document).ready(function ()
        {
            var appViewModel 

            // AppViewModel
            function AppViewModel()
            {
                this.Locations = ko.observable([]);
            }
            var appViewModel = new AppViewModel();

            ko.applyBindings(appViewModel);

            $.getJSON("http://waltweb01:85/LTCEPLWS/LTCJSON.svc/getLTCWithIDs/4", function (data)
            {
                incomingData = data;
                appViewModel.Locations(data.getLTCWithIDsResult.Locations);
            });
        });
    </script>
</asp:Content>
```

Comment: duplicate http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5807155/jquery-currency-format-number

Comment: Not a duplicate. And frankly I can't see how the 13-vote answer at the linked alleged dupe applies to that page's original question.

Comment: Anyway... I've used "<span data-bind="text: formatCurrency(location.Premium)" in order to try and build a return value, but all the formatCurrency function receives is a puking mess of javascript out of it's else branch that (I think) is some function from Knockout.

Comment: function formatCurrency(value)
{
 if (!isNaN(value) && isFinite(value))
 {
  return "$" + value.toFixed(2);
 }
 else
 {
  return "CCB: " + value;
 }
}

Comment: If anything it's a dupe of this: http://stackoverflow.com/q/11751103/1399083  (Can't get this to work either).  Before calling out "duplicate" to someone who really needs help just to make yourself feel big, try helping... or at least learn to search with more than my (admittedly) pittiful skills.

Comment: Is your `Premium` an ko.observable? If you then you need to write `<span data-bind="text: formatCurrency(location.Premium())>` note the parens `()` after `Premium` ... http://jsfiddle.net/kks53/

Comment: That worked pretty well, nemesv!  Thanks much!

Answer (score 3):

Answer is hidden in the comments so to make it easier for future readers here's an answer.

Change your HTML code to:

```
<td><span data-bind="text: formatCurrency(location.Premium())" /> </td>
```

And then add the javascript formatCurrency() function:

```
var formatCurrency = function (amount) {
    if (!amount) {
        return "";
    }
    amount += '';
    x = amount.split('.');
    x1 = x[0];
    x2 = x.length > 1 ? '.' + x[1] : '';
    var rgx = /(\d+)(\d{3})/;
    while (rgx.test(x1)) {
        x1 = x1.replace(rgx, '$1' + ',' + '$2');
    }
    return "$" + x1 + x2;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Knockout has these things called [extenders](http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/extenders.html) which I think are useful in these cases.  The example is for rounding, but it's easy enough to set it up to add a dollar sign or convert the currency.  In this way you can also use the extender in other areas of your site which also need conversion/formatted to dollars.